# Как сделать редирект 301 на wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Нужно сделать редирект с простой ссылки /?p=30 на ссылку с названием поста /name-post/

Страница с адресом /?=30 удалена из wp

Answer (score 0):

прописать в редирект в htaccess или установить плагин какой-нибудь. я пользовался Simple 301 Redirects, там все просто